# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Tag

Tags: python, string, selenium, web-scraping, tags

I have an error. when I try to concatenate the link and the part of next link, where I need to switch.
Here is my error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-172-c75cfd599dcf> in <module>
     21         l.append(j['href'])
     22 
---> 23         url2 = 'https://krisha.kz/prodazha/kvartiry/petropavlovsk/' + ''.join(l[j])
     24         driver.get(url2)
     25 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Tag
```

And I faced problem in the following code:

```
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    links = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'a-card__title'})
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(str(links), 'html.parser')
    href = soup2.find_all('a', href=True)
    l = []
    for j in href:
        l.append(j['href'])
        
        url2 = 'https://krisha.kz/prodazha/kvartiry/petropavlovsk/' + ''.join(l[j])
        driver.get(url2)
```

My **"l"** is a list of hrefs and it looks like that picture below:
[image]

Because of that I can't move to the next page to scrape it. What integer or slice do I need here?

Comment: `l[j]` - j is a tag, not integer

Comment: can I somehow change it, in order to solve the problem?

Comment: `''.join(l[j])` - what is your purpose in this part?

Comment: use  l[j] without brackets  [ ]     =)))

Comment: j is a tag. you can't pass it as index. please clarify what you want to do. what do you expect from `l[j]` to return?

Comment: because when I print  l[j], it outputs [' /smthing ']. And maybe be it somehow impacts on my concatenation. I am not sure

Comment: when i use ``` ''.join ``` it showes me like this  ``` '/a/show/664620637'```. Without square brackets

Comment: @Regid: that is true, but there is no list index `/a/show/664620637` list index is `0`, it is the value that is `/a/show/664620637`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `list` try to use `j` of your loop:

```
url2 = 'https://krisha.kz/prodazha/kvartiry/petropavlovsk/' +j['href'][1:]
```

I sliced it at the end to avoid a `//` in the url.

You also can use the `list` but than you have to `enumerate` in your loop:

```
for i,j in enumerate(href):
    l.append(j['href'])
    url2 = 'https://krisha.kz/prodazha/kvartiry/petropavlovsk/' +l[i][1:]
```

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://krisha.kz/prodazha/kvartiry/petropavlovsk/"


response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'a-card__title'})
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(str(links), 'html.parser')
href = soup2.find_all('a', href=True)
l = []
for j in href:
    l.append(j['href'])

    url2 = 'https://krisha.kz/prodazha/kvartiry/petropavlovsk/' +j['href'][1:]
    print(url2)
```